# EFCore: how to disable any conventions related to relationship discovery?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have model with one-to-one and one-to-many relationships similar to this:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; } // one-to-one reference navigation
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } // one-to-many collection navigation
}
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create two migrations for this model: one with basic CREATE TABLE sql statements and another with foreign keys and constrains according to model relationships, but added relationship navigations are automatically discovered and included in initial migration.

I tried two ways:

1. Disable relationship discovery by `[NotMapped]` attribute or by `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>.Ignore()` method. I think it will work, but I need to find ALL relationship navigations in my code, add `[NotMapped]` attribute, create initial migration, remove ALL added attributes and then create relationships migration.
2. Disable relationship discovery convention by removing `RelationshipDiscoveryConvention` in `ConfigureConventions` method.

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configurationBuilder);
    configurationBuilder.Conventions.Remove(typeof(RelationshipDiscoveryConvention));
}
```

But after disabling `RelationshipDiscoveryConvention` I got new error, similar to this:

`Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Blog.Posts' of type 'ICollection<Post>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

So, removing `RelationshipDiscoveryConvention` does not actually disable relationship discovery but disables configuring class properties as relationship navigations.

What convention I need to remove to disable relationship discovery?

Comment: Why do you want two migrations? Anyway, the easiest way is probably to remove navigation properties from the model temporarily, or mark them as ignored.

Comment: @gert-arnold Well, I already opened a issue on EF Core repo where I was asked the same question. There is an answer: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30906#issuecomment-1550040181